# detecting wrong file format with csv reader

Tags: python, csv

I like to read in a list of ASCII files (utf-8) with the csv reader.
For error handling i like to detect if a user has seleted by accident a file which cannot be read.
The source is like this:

```
    for File in Filenames:
    print ('... processing file :',File)
    with open(File, 'r') as csvfile:
        Reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter = ';')           
        for Line in Reader:
            print(Line)
```

I the user selects e.g. file which is GZIPed i got the message:

(result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8b in position 1: invalid start byte

Which in the first place is ok, but the script crashes.
I didn't found out how to capture the error and force the script to jump to the next file in the list. I found a lot of about dialects and other codecs, but my task is not to read the wrong file by just changing the codec.

Many thanks for any comment!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
for File in Filenames:
    print ('... processing file :',File)
    with open(File, 'r') as csvfile:
        try:
            Reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter = ';')           
            for Line in Reader:
                print(Line)
        except UnicodeDecodeError as e:
            print("File {:} cannot be read. Skipping...".format(csvfile))
            continue
```

Answer (score 0):

Use exception handling - https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html

Your code would then look like:

```
for File in Filenames:
    print ('... processing file :',File)
    try:
        with open(File, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as csvfile:
            Reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter = ';')           
            for Line in Reader:
                print(Line)
    except UnicodeDecodeError:
         pass
```

It's good practice to include the encoding you expect when you open the file. If you put the same script on a Windows box, the default encoding would not be "utf-8".

Comment: do you really have to wrap the `with` in the `try` too? Can it through an error as well?

Comment: IIRC, it's the TextWrapper of `open()` that throws the UnicodeDecodeError.

Comment: Thanks a lot for that!